# NumPy mmap: "ValueError: Size of available data is not a multiple of data-type size."

Tags: python, numpy, mmap

I'm trying to get data from "data.txt" into a numpy array and plot it with matplotlib. This is what each line of the data looks like:

"1" 11.658870417634 4.8159509459201

with about ten million lines.

I'm trying to get it into a memory map, but keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: Size of available data is not a multiple of data-type size.
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datatype=[('index',numpy.int), ('floati',numpy.float32), ('floatq',numpy.float32)]
filename='data.txt'

def main():
    data = numpy.memmap(filename, datatype, 'r') 
    plt.plot(data['floati'],data['floatq'],'r,')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.title("Signal-Diagram")
    plt.xlabel("Sample")
    plt.ylabel("In-Phase")
    plt.savefig('foo2.png')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you could please help me figure out where I'm going wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @nneonneo has pointed out the problem with your code in the answer below. You may also want to look at [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library; in particular [IO Tools](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html).

Answer (score 3):

That's a text file, not a binary file. `memmap` only works if the data is stored as binary (i.e. stored as the array would be stored in memory).

You can convert the file to binary by reading it in, line-by-line, and storing each converted line in a writable `memmap`.

Comment: Is there an advantage in converting to binary first besides just reading the text file as with `genfromtxt` or `loadtxt`?

Comment: If you will need to use the data often, it is better to save it in a faster format. You only need to convert once, after which you can run the program using `memmap`. That will run *much* faster.

Comment: You mean when you save the file in the first place, not in the case where you're reading the file?  Because when you read it, you are saving it as a numpy array for use, right?

Comment: With plain `genfromtxt`/`loadtxt` you read the array into memory, but you don't necessarily save the array anywhere. Then when the program is launched again, it will have to read the whole array again, doing all the parsing necessary to read the text file. If you make a binary file once, then it will be fast to open the file in the future.

Comment: I see, thanks.  For that purpose I've only used `np.save` and `np.savez` which is easy but presumably more limited.

Answer (score 2):

You're better off using `numpy.genfromtxt` or `numpy.loadtxt`.  For example:

```
datatype=[('index',numpy.int), ('floati',numpy.float32), ('floatq',numpy.float32)]
filename='data.txt'

def main():
    data = numpy.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=datatype) 
    ...
```

Comment: +1 Excellent suggestion. This is probably the simplest way to solve the OP's issue.