# Is there a way to load a numpy unicode array into a memmap?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-memmap

I am trying to create an array of `dtype='U'` and saving that using `numpy.save()`, however, when trying to load the saved file into a `numpy.memmap` I get an error related to the size not being a multiple of 'U3'

I am working with `python 3.5.2`. I have tried the following code where I am creating an empty array and another array with 3 entries, all with length of 3 letters and then save the array into `file1.npy` file.

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.empty((1, 0), dtype='U')
arr2 = np.array(['111', '222', '333'], dtype='U')
arr = np.concatenate((arr, arr2), axis = None)
print(arr)
np.save('file1', arr)

rArr = np.memmap('file1.npy', dtype='U3', mode='r')
```

However, when I try to load the file into a `numpy.memmap` I get the the following error `ValueError: Size of available data is not a multiple of the data-type size.`

Is there a way to load the data into a `numpy.memmap` using strings? I feel I am missing something simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy mmap: "ValueError: Size of available data is not a multiple of data-type size."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303087/numpy-mmap-valueerror-size-of-available-data-is-not-a-multiple-of-data-type-s)

Comment: I saw that question but I am not sure how it is a duplicate. The saved file is a binary file. I believe there is another reason I am getting the error like some extra data in the file I am not aware of.

Comment: Have you tried `np.load` with `mmap_mode`?

Comment: @hpaulj, this actually worked. I can't believe I missed it. I was trying different things and I forgot to test with `np.load` and `mmap_mode`. 

On the other hand, to address my original question I believe I found the answer as well. When using `numpy.save`, it seems the resulted file has a header if I delete that header (the first line in the file) and use `numpy.memmap` I am able to load the data properly. So I am guessing `memmap` was more directed for manually saved files without using `numpy.save`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files used by [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) are raw binary files, not [NPY-format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#npy-format) files.  If you want to read a memory-mapped NPY file, use [`numpy.load`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) with the argument `mmap_mode='r'` (or whatever other value is appropriate).

After creating 'file1.npy' like you did, here's how it can be memory-mapped with `numpy.load`:

```
In [16]: a = np.load('file1.npy', mmap_mode='r')                                                                       

In [17]: a                                                                                                             
Out[17]: memmap(['111', '222', '333'], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: Thanks, this confirmed my suspicion about `memmap`. So I will have to manually save the binary data that would be loaded later). `np.load()` works fine.

Comment: Alternatively, you can save a raw binary file, which is via `array.tofile()`, and then load it with `memmap`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `np.load` is your friend here.

[Doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html)

[Issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12926)

The following snippet works for me:

```
rArr = np.load('file1.npy', mmap_mode='r')
```